# Pandas groupby NaN/None values in non-key columns

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, nan

Where there are NaN/None values in columns which aren't groupby key columns, when `last()` is used, it seems groupby is doing some sort of filling:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 1, 2], 'b': [23, 43, np.nan, 12], 'c': ['x', 'y', 'z', None]})
   a     b     c
0  1  23.0     x
1  2  43.0     y
2  1   NaN     z
3  2  12.0  None
```

```
df.groupby(by='a', as_index=False, dropna=False).last()
   a     b  c
0  1  23.0  z
1  2  12.0  y
```

where expected output is

```
   a     b     c
0  1   NaN     z
1  2  12.0  None
```

`dropna=False` doesn't help because it only applies to groupby column 'a'. Is there a way to make pandas not ignore NaN/None values without a hack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`last` is designed to get the last non-NA value, independently in each column.

What you want (last row per group) is [`tail`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html):

```
df.groupby(by='a', as_index=False).tail(1)
```

Output:

```
   a     b     c
2  1   NaN     z
3  2  12.0  None
```